# How to write an app for kindle 4/5?

Tags: kindle, kindle-kdk

Do You know, how to write an app for Kindle 4? Kindle Fire have KDK, but is there a possibility to write an app for Kindle 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kindle Fire actually [uses Android as its platform](https://developer.amazon.com/welcome.html), not the [KDK](http://kdk.amazon.com/gp/public/gateway). The Kindle 4/5 both run applications created with the KDK.

Comment: is there any way to get KDK without asking amazon? I've asked for it but i didn't get any answer :/

Comment: Unfortunately, no -- you need to ask Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

**Kindle 4:**

It seams you cannot register as a developer for the old Kindle anymore, so you need to jailbreak it and use a key (that you create yourself) to sign your jars.

You can find instructions what to do and several resources at the URL mentioned below.

There is also a tool to create your own Kindle developer key.

You need to install the public key on your Kindle. To be able to use your jars that you sign with it.

A Hello-World example is also included on the website.

It is also explained how to use retroweaver that makes it possible to use java 1.5 and than convert it to 1.4.

http://cowlark.com/kindle/getting-started.html

P.s.
Please add a comment as soon as you successfully wrote your first app that runs on your kindle.